# Spring Boot ApplicationListener not running at app startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

I have created a [spring-boot-troubleshooting repo on GitHub](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting) that reproduces this error exactly.

I am building a Spring Boot-based REST service and am having difficulty getting a [startup listener](https://github.com/bitbythecron/spring-boot-troubleshooting/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/example/bitbythecron/springboottroubleshooting/StartupListener.groovy) to work:

```
@Slf4j
class StartupListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Autowired
    ScheduledReporter metricReporter

    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        log.info('StartupListener is starting...')
        metricReporter.start(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
}
```

When I run the app:

```
./gradlew build && java -Dspring.config=. -jar build/libs/spring-boot-troubleshooting.jar
```

Everything starts up without errors/exceptions, however I never see my "*StartupListener is starting...*" log message print to the console. This tells me Spring is *not* firing up my `StartupListener`. Any ideas what the fix is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class is not a spring bean(I looked into the file in repo as well), So spring hasn't scanned this at all. And hence this is never called.
Try adding `@Component` for this class.